# Get status when running job without hadoop

Tags: hadoop

When I run a hadoop job with the hadoop application it prints a lot of stuff. Among them, It show the relative progress of the job ("map: 30%, reduce: 0%" and stuff like that). But, when running a job without the application it does not print anything, not even errors. Is there a way to get that level of logging without the application? That is, without running `[hadoop_folder]/bin/hadoop jar <my_jar> <indexer> <args>...`.

Comment: Please explain "without the application"

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from [Application Master](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) (assuming you use YARN and not MR1 where you would get it from Job Tracker). There is usually web UI where you can find this information. Details will depend on your Hadoop installation / distribution.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Hadoop v1 check Job tracker web URL and in case of Hadoop v2 check Application Master web UI